# Как поместить variable в colspan

Tags: html, веб-программирование, xml, xpath, xslt

Есть вот такой кусок кода :

```
<xsl:variable name="crow" select="count(row)"/>

<td colspan="$crow">Бла бла бла</td>
```

Но он не работает. Почему-то colspan вообще не работает с переменными.. или я не понимаю как их передать,рыскал по html докам но ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать фигурные скобки:

```
<td colspan="{$crow}">Бла бла бла</td>
```

Фигурные скобки заставляют текст внутри кавычек обрабатываться как выражение XPath, а не интерпретироваться как литеральная строка.